# Dollar Sign with Dot Notation?

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

In Javascript (Titanium), what does the dollar sign mean when it's used in place of the variable name?

```
$.result.text = e.name+': $'+e.price;
```

Below is an example of a Titanium 'fireEvent', where a view is receiving data from an object, assigned to the variable name **$.result.text**.  It appears to be dot notation, but I'm not sure what variable the dollar sign represents.

Is this a wild card character or reference to the receiving object?  I've tried to research more info on this, but most searches come back with jquery or php type info.  I'm not using jquery, so not sure how it would apply here.

Here is more detail from the example I'm referencing:

When the table view is clicked, the following code is executed.

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('MVC:tab:itemSelected', {
         name:e.rowData.title,
         price:e.rowData.price
     });
```

The following is the corresponding event listener in detail.js:

```
   Ti.App.addEventListener('MVC:tab:itemSelected', function(e) {
     $.result.text = e.name+': $'+e.price;
});
```

Comment: It's not used in place of a variable name, it _is_ a variable name.

Comment: Thanks Teemu.  Does the variable represent an object?  I'm just not sure where it's defined as a variable or what object it is...my guess is its the receiving object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` sign in Titanium is the current window object. So your `$` object includes a `result` object which has a `text` property. So you are right, it is dot notation.

Basic example for the $ reference (from [the official docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_XML_Markup), which are quite good!):

XML:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <Widget src="mywidget" id="foo" name="foo" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

JS:

```
$.index.open();
$.foo.myMethod();
```

Comment: The Alloy Views section, I should have thought of that!  Thanks for the help.  Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: In this case it is the Window. A view inside this window would be referenced as $.myView

Comment: I have just seen that you are new here at SO. If the answer is correct please mark it as accepted to show other people that you have found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for the specific answer:

'$.' Identifies UI elements in the controller (prefixed with '$.') and style sheet (prefixed with '#'). IDs should be unique per view but are not global, so multiple views can have components with the same ID.